# How this query works to get first day of current month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, Getdate()), 0),
'First Day of Current Month'
```

Can anyone tell me how this query works to get the first day of current month?

Comment: you want day to be displayed in in number or alphebets like Sunday, Monday

Comment: I don't get it, you want to know the weekday of the first day in the month?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly

Datediff(month, 0, Getdate()) will give will give total months from 1900

and from 1900 you add the months returned by the above months, so you will get month's first date

Eg : if we take present month then

Datediff(month, 0, Getdate())  = 1349 months

and if you add 1349 months to the '1900/01/01' you will get this months first date '2012/06/01'

Answer (score 5):

[`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)/[`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794)

This pattern can be used to achieve a number of different effects. The general pattern is:

```
DATEADD(part,DATEDIFF(part,x,z),y)
```

Where `part` is the same component of a date, `x` and `y` are usually constants, and `z` is the date to adjust.

When `x` and `y` are set to the *same* constant, then it has the effect of eliminating all components of `z` beyond the `part` element, and replacing those components with the corresponding ones from `y`. (`0` is treated the same as `1900-01-01T00:00:00`)

So, `SELECT Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, Getdate()), 0)` takes the current date (`z` = `GetDate()`), and replaces those parts of it beyond the `month` (`day` and all time components) with the corresponding parts from `1900-01-01T00:00:00`.

To get the start of today, you would use:

```
DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

---

Where this pattern gets more entertaining is that it can be used to achieve "offsetting" effects when `x` and `y` are not equal. For instance, to get the last day of last month, you can do:

```
DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20001231')
```

Here, the actual values of `x` and `y` don't matter so much. What does matter is the relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

i thing you need this. It will give you the name and number of first day of current month.

```
SELECT DatePart(DW,DATEADD(DD,-DAY(GetDate())+1,GetDate())) FirstDayNumber
     , DateName(DW,DATEADD(DD,-DAY(GetDate())+1,GetDate()))  FirstDayName
```

Answer (score 0):

select DATEADD(MM,datediff(month,0,getdate()),0) first_day_of_month

go

select DATEADD(mm,datediff(month,0,getdate())+1,0)-1 last_day_of_currentmonth

Comment: Please expand - how this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
DATEADD(DAY, (-1 * DATEPART(DAY,GetDate()) + 1), GetDate() )
```

Basically, we're adding the negative days + 1 to the current date.